# Fragment not clear on memory heap after destroyed

Tags: android, android-fragments, out-of-memory, heap-memory

In my app i use backstack for my fragment and popBackStack to back previous fragment.

I have problem when i back to previous fragment by popBackStack. (FragmentA->FragmentB->FragmentA). I see that in fragmentB when popBackStack to previous fragmentA, It's called `onDestroy` method. I find FragmentB in `getFragmentManager().getFragments()` but I can found it.

However, When i dump memory heap, I find x FragmentB on heap (i open fragment B x times). It increase my memory heap and then I got error `OutOFMemory` when I repeat flows A->B->A until full heap.

I cannot find any solution or cause of my problem. Is there any suggestion for my problem?

Comment: You should check to see if there is any strong reference to FragmentB that wasn't freed on destroying. And if possible,  share your code snippets here so everyone can give you advice.

Comment: sorry i cannot share my code. I have create sample project like my flows app in here: https://github.com/sinhpn92/FragmentStackTest.
I my sample it haven't this problem. But in my project, i have problem above. I don't know why? Is there any cause for this problem?

Comment: did you resolve this ?

Answer (score 0):

1> Try to maintain the fragment in the stack (add a popup while you are adding the new fragment)

For Example:

```
private Stack<Fragment> fragmentStack = new Stack<Fragment>();

// code to add new fragment in stack and previous fragment in back stack 
FragmentTransaction ft = fragmentManager.beginTransaction();

Fragment mFragment = new Fragment(); // you can replace this with your fragment
ft.add(R.id.container, mFragment); // you can also add fragment id so that if you can reuse that fragment if it is memory.
fragmentStack.lastElement().onPause();
ft.hide(fragmentStack.lastElement());
fragmentStack.push(resultListFragment);
ft.commit();

// code to remove visible fragment from top and resume back stack fragment
if (fragmentStack.size() == 2)// used to check whether their is any fragment in stack is yes than go for back event like onbackbutton event { 
    FragmentTransaction ft = fragmentManager.beginTransaction();
    fragmentStack.lastElement().onPause();
    ft.remove(fragmentStack.pop());
    fragmentStack.lastElement().onResume();
    ft.show(fragmentStack.lastElement());
    ft.commit();
}
```

2> If the above code snippet doesn't solve your problem for `OutOFMemory` error, then use `setRetaininstance(true)` in `onCreate(Bundle)` system callback method of the fragment lifecycle so it will not create a new fragment if its already the in memory.